# Creating and deleting files in Maven test/resources directory

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am trying to write some unit tests for a java servlet that can write and delete files. I have config.properties files for my dev and prod builds, as well as one that lives in test/resources that only gets called during tests. I write to a temp file that is later deleted.

canceled.filepath=src/test/resources/Cancel.txt
temp.filepath=src/test/resources/Cancel_temp.txt

My issue is that I get an error thrown from the servlet saying I can't delete the temp file. I assume this is due to a permissions error. Is there anywhere I can make these files so my unit tests and have full permission to wirte/delete?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create the temp file in the default temporary directory of your system? [`Files.createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-). Using JUnit, you can also use a [`TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html)

Comment: the config file acutally gives the servlet the path where we want to perform file operations. So the servlet itself is writing and deleting the files. I did try to give it a path to a temp directory, but the delete still doesn't complete

Comment: The servlet should only get configuration by the `ServletConfig`. If you do this then you can call the `Servlet.init(ServletConfig)` method in your test and specify a test config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Junit 4 **TemporaryFolder** Rule to manage the filesystem interactions for you.

```
public class MyTestClass {
 //MUST be public
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
   //You can create new files.
    File tmpFile = tempFolder.newFile();
    System.out.println(tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(tmpFile.exists());

    //Or new Folders
    File myFolder = tempFolder.newFolder("My_Folder");
    System.out.println(myFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(myFolder.exists());

    //or a combination of them.
    File newFileInMyFolder = tempFolder.newFile("My_Folder\\subfile.txt");
    System.out.println(newFileInMyFolder.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(newFileInMyFolder.exists());

    // The Junit rule uses the system property 'java.io.tempdir' to create them, and it handles the cleanup outside
    // the scope of your test!
    }
}
```

Output:

```
    C:\Users\Jeremiah\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4815976615865849247\junit796088998678325697.tmp
true
C:\Users\Jeremiah\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4815976615865849247\My_Folder
true
C:\Users\Jeremiah\AppData\Local\Temp\junit4815976615865849247\My_Folder\subfile.txt
true
```

> After the text executes, the Rule implementation handles all clean-up,
>   as long as the files were created using the Rule.

Based on your question, you can probably set your System properties in an *@Before* block and then trust that they're present for the context of the active test.

```
public class MyServletTest {
    //MUST be public
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Before
    public void setTestPaths() throws Exception {
        File cancelFile = tempFolder.newFile("Cancel.txt");
        File cancelTemp = tempFolder.newFile("Cancel_temp.txt");

        System.setProperty("canceled.filepath", cancelFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.setProperty("temp.filepath", cancelTemp.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    @After
    public void restorePaths() {
        //FIXME:  The JVM will be reused, if you have any other tests relying on the system properites they will be getting the values set in the BEFORE block.
    }

    @Test
    public void checkSysVars() {
        String cancelPath = System.getProperty("canceled.filepath");
        String tmpPath = System.getProperty("temp.filepath");

        File cancelFile = new File(cancelPath);
        File cancelTemp = new File(tmpPath);
        System.out.println(cancelFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(cancelFile.exists());
        System.out.println(cancelTemp.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(cancelTemp.exists());

    }
}
```

Again, console output:

```
C:\Users\Jeremiah\AppData\Local\Temp\junit7380201043103411996\Cancel.txt
true
C:\Users\Jeremiah\AppData\Local\Temp\junit7380201043103411996\Cancel_temp.txt
true
```